# When banner ad not loaded a white space appears in its place

Tags: java, android, banner-ads

My app has a banner ad at the bottom.It takes some time load.While it loads a white space appears in its place as shown below:
[image]

How do i slove this problem.Should improve the loading speed of the banner ad or do something with my xml layout.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.gametalks.MainActivity"

    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/no_internet_view"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No Internet Connection!"/>
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/retry_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Retry"/>
</LinearLayout>



   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_above="@id/adView">
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/listView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          ></ListView>
      </LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>


   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
       xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

       ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
   </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should upload at least the relevant part of the xml layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `android:layout_above="@id/adView` from list container and add to your `ListView` paddingBottom = height_of_your_banner (or about it) and add `android:clipToPadding="false"`. Now your listview will fill whole screen and if you scroll to bottom - you will be able to see al items without overlap from banner. Also you can remove odd containers from `ListView` so instead of:

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_above="@id/adView">
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/listView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          ></ListView>
      </LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>
```

Will be just:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Comment: but how do i know the height of my banner?Will it be same on all devices?Thanks

Comment: you can use AdSize.getHeightInPixels(Context). In your case you can get size by: AdSize.SMART_BANNER.getHeightInPixels(Context)

Comment: @ArjunAnil so you can write:`int height = AdSize.SMART_BANNER.getHeightInPixels(this);
listView.setClipToPadding(false);
listView.setPadding(0,0,0, height);`